# data cataloging for sql server using Amundsen,lyft

Tags: catalog

I would like to use a open source data cataloging tool in my company and was evaluating **Amundsen** for the same. I have a lot of sql server on my onPremise and would like to catalog all those in Amunsen. Currently for POC I am using docker containers for Amundsen on my local machine.

Could not find any help in cataloging my sql server tables. Can anyone please help me on how to do it in Amundsen, Lyft

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem. 
found that the SQL server extractor had a few bugs, so I made a pull request to fix them and added a sample script to build.

https://github.com/lyft/amundsendatabuilder/pull/272

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this to work? It seems like the're still a few things wrong with the code. E.g. "AttributeError: 'MSSQLMetadataExtractor' object has no attribute '_extract_iter'".

Comment: the pull request got included into the master branch, connector was running fine last time I checked.